# Can one display multiple Mat-Dialogs at same time

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to display a mat dialog over another mat-dailog component ? I have a grid which has an edit button and when user clicks on the edit i open a component in a matDialog window which allows the user to edit the data. Now if user wants to close that Edit window without saving the data i want to go and show a new mat-dialog over the Edit Dialog asking if he wants to discard the unsaved data. I have the logic working fine but for some reason it does not display the 2nd dialog. The original dialog becomes inactive and that's where i am stuck. this is what it looks like

[image]

So my question is can you display more then one mat-dialog in modal mode and if so how would you go about arranging them so they are displayed correctly.

Comment: maybe have a look at the z-index of your component or directly import dialog component inside your first dialog

Answer (score 0):

I was there in past in same problem but i went little far and I code own full dialog system similar to mat dialog but little different, with more functionality that support multiple dialogs, added token functionality under the hood so developer can call dialog above dialog in cronological order, button generator with observables and so on.

Later I put little more effort and put it in open source library, there are stackblitz examples too:

https://costlydeveloper.github.io/ngx-awesome-popup/#/playground/dialog-showcase